# How to lists different image-formats recursively in a tree?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

How would I efficiently go about searching for `.png | .svg | .xpm` image-files in a complex and recursively structured hierarchy in one query, using terminal (and if possible `|` (pipe) `tree` in the same query, to get a nice output/overview, like in the example below:

├── arrows
│   ├── submenu01.png
│   └── submenu02.png
├── awesome
    ├── 01
    │   ├── ac.png
    │   ├── awesome.png
    │   ├── bat_low.png
    │   ├── bat_no.png
    │   │   ├── close_normal_all.png
    │   │   ├── floating_focus_inactive.png
    │   │   ├── floating_normal_active.png
    │   ├── vol_low.png
    │   ├── vol_mute.png
    │   ├── vol_no.png
    │   ├── vol_up.png
    │   └── widget_bg.png
    ├── antilight_by_sunjack94-d3ddff6.tar
    ├── As_It_Fades_by_synorgy.png

---

I'd like to do this in:

```
/usr/share/
```

Any help is highly appreciated, even if it doesn't fully fit my request!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install the package `tree` than use

```
tree -P '*.png|*.svg|*.xpm' --prune /usr/share/
```

Comment: I am getting "tree: Invalid argument -`-'." when using `--prune`. and I did not found this option in man pages. Would you plz put some light :)

Comment: Copy and paste the command.

Comment: Sorry. ``--prune`` needs at least Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: (Or you could just pull tree back [from a later release](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tree&searchon=names&section=all))

Comment: Thank you Florian for your answer and sorry for the late reply. Is there any alternative to `prune` you know of for 11.10 that i could use?! I'll try Olis' suggestion and if that doesn't work I'll wait a few days before I accept your answer. +1